# Dividing A row in Matlab to N submattices

Tags: matlab, split, row

I have a row of data (1*1211). I want to split this row to sub matrices with the dimension (1*7). is there any way? I tried to use mat2cell but  seems doesnt work here. Thank you so much and waiting for any nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

doc reshape

and

```
reshape(data, 7, [])'
```